# Change bootstrap tooltip css on focus

Tags: jquery, css, tooltip

I want to change the background color of a manually triggered tooltip.

I have some input fields made using bootstrap. Following is the HTML.

## HTML

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
            <form method="post" action="index.php">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="rn">Student ID:</label>
                        <input type="text" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Your ID goes here" class="form-control" id="rn" name="rn" data-trigger="manual">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="fname">Student Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" title="Your Name goes here" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="manual">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="deg">Student Degree:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="deg" name="deg" title="Your Degree Program goes here" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="manual">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="cam">Student Campus:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cam" name="cam" title="Your University Campus goes here" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="manual">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="city">Student City:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" title="Your University City goes here" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="manual">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="save" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

I am getting tooltips to show on focus if field is empty.

## jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#rn, #fname, #deg, #cam, #city").focus(function(){
                if(!$(this).val()){
                    $(this).tooltip("show");
                }
            });
            $("#rn, #fname, #deg, #cam, #city").blur(function(){
                $(this).tooltip("hide");
            });
        });
```

I am using CSS to change the background color of the tooltip but it is not working. I got this code from another post.

## CSS

```
.form-control + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner{
    background-color: #EE022C;
}
```

Comment: Your code works .Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/4co8yt1m/4/)  fiddle.

Comment: @Swati, did you change the code?
update: it worked on fiddle, not on opera. i ran it on microsoft edge and it worked.

Comment: Can you kindly check why [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jxk8wfb7/) is not working?

Comment: Its being overriden by bootstrap default, use `border: 1px solid red !important;`

Comment: shouldn't the new code be overridden?

Comment: Bootstrap code has more specificity in this case, thus using `important` we make it this CSS the most specific CSS which gets applied!

Comment: Thanks guys. the code works now. one question though, why does code work on one browser(microsoft edge) and not the other(opera stable)?

Comment: Each browser is built from different engines providing varied support to ECMA Scripts, CSS properties and so on. If you wish to check which browsers support a specific syntax you can check from [here](https://caniuse.com/). Thus, modern browsers provide support to all latest ES6+ scripts whereas older browsers like IE8, 10 have limited support and so additional plugin or code needs to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Check if this works for you!!

modified the css selector to just `.tooltip > .tooltip-inner`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#rn, #fname, #deg, #cam, #city").focus(function() {
    if (!$(this).val()) {
      $(this).tooltip("show");
    }
  });
  $("#rn, #fname, #deg, #cam, #city").blur(function() {
    $(this).tooltip("hide");
  });
});
```

```css
.tooltip > .tooltip-inner {  background-color: #EE022C !important;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="rn">Student ID:</label>
          <input type="text" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Your ID goes here" class="form-control" id="rn" name="rn" data-trigger="manual">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="fname">Student Name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" title="Your Name goes here" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="manual">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="deg">Student Degree:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="deg" name="deg" title="Your Degree Program goes here" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="manual">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="cam">Student Campus:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cam" name="cam" title="Your University Campus goes here" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="manual">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="city">Student City:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" title="Your University City goes here" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="manual">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" name="save" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
      </div>
```